# Разбить строку на разряды в PHP

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Есть строка типа "100000". Как разбить ее на разряды в php, чтобы было "100 000"?.

Comment: @duddeniska, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`number_format()`](http://www.php.su/number_format())
Для особых извращенцев, можно использовать `preg_match()/preg_replace()` (ссылки уже не помню, но видел реализацию), но тогда дорога одна: [сюда](http://govnokod.ru).

Answer (score 1):

ого...
зачем жеж так жестоко... регулярки....
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
$number = 100000;
echo number_format($number, 2, ',', ' '); // выведет 100 000,00
echo number_format($number, 0, ',', ' '); // Соответственно будет 100 000
```

Comment: Уже есть этот ответ, второй как вариант (не всё же в одной позе... эмн... функции делать?).  
Как вопрос закрыть?

Comment: > Как вопрос закрыть?

@TheDoctor, Вы сперва 3К наберите.

Comment: @romeo, что такое "ЗК"?  
Да, я буквально вчера зарегался, извините, ещё не освоился.

Comment: @TheDoctor  Кроме того, причины закрытия чужого вопроса должны [быть вескими](http://hashcode.ru/privileges/close-questions)

Comment: @romeo, вроде причина веская - дан хороший и точный ответ, остальное может быть только холиваром или размышлениями на тему как разобрать число в 100500 циклах и проверках, что как-то... не кошерно.

Comment: @TheDoctor. вот выжимка

>  Вопросы, которые являются бесполезными, должны быть закрыты. Вопросы, которые являются дубликатами более старых вопросов, также должны быть закрыты.

Если следовать Вашей логики, то на форуме необходимо закрывать все вопросы, ответы на которые одобрены (имеют подтверждение) задающий стороной([ТС](http://teenslang.su/id/10279))

> ...дан хороший и точный ответ, остальное может быть только холиваром или размышлениями

Для этого и существует система рейтингования. Если вопрос "проходной", то уже завтра о нём никто и не вспомнит.

Comment: @romeo, Я знаю что такое ТС, благодарю :)  
Лично мне эта логика нравится - ответ получен, значит закрыть.  
Хотя не мне решать, я предложил и не более.